# jQuery removing checkboxes where index is between two values

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following jQuery code:

**Working code**

```
$( '.spanspec:gt(49)' ).remove();
```

This removes all checkboxes in my code with the class `spanspec` where the `index` is greater than 49.  Works fine.

**Non-working code**

```
$( '.spanspec:between(41, 46)' ).remove();
```

What I would like to achieve is to remove multiple checkboxes that have an index between two values.  I have tried the above but this does not work.

Please note that I am familiar with the use of `:gt :lt :eq` but using these in this instance does deliver the desired result.

Any help, advice or feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('.spanspec').slice(41,46).remove();
```

Here's a smaller, generic **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k4u5Y/)**. Note that the range in slice() is zero based, and will go up until (but not including) the index of the second parameter.

Comment: That is perfect and exactly what I was looking for in terms of the final results.  Thank you, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should do the work

```
$('.spanspec:gt(41):lt(46)').remove();
```

also you can try something like:

```
$('.spanspec').slice(41, 46).remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for this - `.slice():` gives me the desired result.